# search form always called

Tags: python, django

There is an error in def search : The view encyclopedia.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Only when I call a create new Page. I don't understand why?

My layout template with search bar:

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>

                <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="q"  placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>

                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'new' %}">Create New Page</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Random Page
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

My new template:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    New Entry
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>New entry</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'new' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def search(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST['q']

        if util.get_entry(title):
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/wiki.html", {
                    "entry": util.get_entry(title),
                    "title": title})

        if util.get_partial_entry(title):

            return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
                        "entries": util.get_partial_entry(title)
                        })

        return render(request, "encyclopedia/404.html", {
            "entry": title})


def new(request, method="GET"):

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/new.html", {
        "form": NewForm()
    })
```

I don t understand why I have only the error on new page and not on index for example?
thanks for help

Comment: I understand but I don t know which default return I can add as it is in a layout.html ? and be accessed by every page of my site ?

Comment: just import `from django.http import HttpResponse` and return `HttpResponse('')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `def search(request)` if request method is not `POST` the function will return None. you need to add a default return value.